# Missing image handle with promise

Tags: angularjs, promise

I would like to load tons on images in the background from urls, and if one of them isn't available, don't load, just throw an error message. I created a service for this in AngularJS, and my problem is, I can't handle the unavailable images error.

```
app.service('Images', ['$q', '$http', function ($q, $http) {
  this.loadImage = function (uri) {

            var deffered = $q.defer();

            var img = new Image();
            img.onerror = function() {
                deffered.resolve(false);
            };
            img.onload = function () {
                console.log('img loaded');
            };

            img.src = uri;
            return deffered.promise;
        };
        return this;
    }]);
```

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/PKTxji69tZ9cTPpXYjnb?p=preview)

When I handle the returned promise, it shouldn't drop an error in the browser console. The `onload` function shouldn't run if the `onerror` executed. I don't know, what is the different [with this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/u5F6FfO3dEkNSMYV1amo?p=preview), the base of my code. (I tried to use factory, but it didn't help.)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your Image class does but I think you need to use

`deffered.reject(false);`

instead of

`deffered.resolve(false);`

Also img.onload should change to

```
 img.onload = function () {
    deffered.resolve(img);
 };
```

Comment: I tried it to, the `error 404` still there, the onload run also.
In the another example it works fine, i would need the same result, but I cannot reproducate.

Comment: The error seems to be coming because it the behavior of Image object to get the image from server, nothing to do with angular.

Comment: It's okay, but my problem is, I should generate a base64 image in the `onload` function, but only, if it's loaded, valid. In this case, how should I handle **in** the `onload` function the image load error?